# Listening a short sentence from a movie in English and figure out what it suppose to be said

Tags: learning-methods

English is my second language and I have trouble listening and figuring out what it's said when spoken fast in English.

This is the sentence.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RgEQwgIe0OJ0WVjwwvsve7917bAWsfjy

As you can see, the sentence is easy. But no matter how I listen to, the only thing I can hear was "Can’t leave your photo boss leaves, Davis." instead of "Can’t leave before boss leaves, Davis.", even now.

If you have any tips for me to listen properly, please tell me anything that could help.

Comment: Hi S J, welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Could you please take the [tour] and look around in the help section to become familiar with this site? I have temporarily closed your question because it looks like a duplicate of an older question. (It's always a good idea to do a search first!) If you clarify how your question differs from the other question, it may get reopened again. However, if your question is just about that specific English sentence, it is off topic here.

Comment: It *might* be on-topic on English Language Learners: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Listen for the 'b' sound at the end of 'leave'. The 'v' is hardly there at all and I think you are hearing the 'b' sound as part of 'leave'. Also, it's *can't leave before THE boss leaves* - the bit that you are hearing as *to* (in *photo*) is actually *the*. Listen to the bit you have down as *pho* and think about whether it is really the same vowel sound as in *hotel*, and not the one you find in *more*.